# Initialization file not loading in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, initialization

I'm trying to go through the complicated process of getting Emacs to work as a Python IDE. However, the `.emacs` file doesn't seem to be loading. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> shows me that `user-init-file` is what it should be, `/home/txx/.emacs`. However, my `load-path` doesn't include what I want it to, such as `~/.emacs.d/`.

The code in my `.emacs` file is pretty long, so I have put it in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PpXW3nnW).

I'm using Fedora 16. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `Pastebin` - it looks as though the double quotes surrounding the paths you want to add to your `load-path` are not recognized.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path “~/.emacs.d/”)
```

You should use the standard `"` (which you use later on in your .emacs).

At least, that solves the first error I get when trying to load your .emacs.

Comment: My `load-path` is not correct.   I've put my output on CodeTidy because Pastebin is being ridiculously slow. http://codetidy.com/2782/ And what's with this 5-min comment editing thing?

Comment: Open up your .emacs in Emacs, and after each expression (starting at the top), type `C-x C-e` (which should be bound to `eval-last-sexp`) and see if you get any errors.  The first one that has an error will show you where the problem is.  I get no problem after evaluating the `(add-to-list ...)` once I changed the double quotes to be just " - the load path is set appropriately.

Comment: I just killed my process and restarted it. That seems to work. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You really do not want the `~/.emacs.d` directory to be in your `load-path`, trust me (you will bump into weird misbehaviors sooner or later if you do).  If you want to install packages somewhere in `~/.emacs.d`, then put them in some sub-directory (e.g. `~/.emacs.d/packages`) and then add that sub-directory to your `load-path`.